# Deploying ASP.NET application on IIS 7; got compilerVersion issue

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am trying to deploy two `ASP.NET` Application onto `IIS 7`. The first application I copied and pasted under `wwwRooT` folder and set Application Pool as `Asp.NET 4.0 Integrated`. For the second one, I created one virtual directory and set the Application Pool the same as the first application.

The first one works well, but the second one got exception:

> The value for the 'compilerVersion' attribute in the provider options
>   must be 'v4.0' or later if you are compiling for version 4.0 or later of the .NET
>   Framework. To compile this Web application for version 3.5 or earlier of the .NET 
>   Framework, remove the 'targetFramework' attribute from the  element of 
>   the Web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and had to tell ASP.NET in configuration to use the 3.5 compiler as follows by modifying Web.config. 
I've copied and pasted the following from my code. You have to change value="v3.5" to value="v4.0". The compiler type strings might also change.

```
<configuration>

  <!--  ... other configuraiton stuff ... -->

  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider,System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
        <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

</configuration>
```

In my case the 2.0 compiler was being used instead of 3.5. I was working in an IIS 7, ASP.NET Website project.
You might glean additional insight from:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a15ebt6c%28VS.80%29.aspx